# Connect gnosis-safe (safe) wallet to UI

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe

What's the best way to connect a Gnosis-Safe to a UI so that I can create transactions based off the UI of an app?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [walletconnect](https://walletconnect.com/).

Most web3 apps have Wallet Connect will give you a QR code. You can then copy that QR code and paste it directly into your [safe wallet connect app](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40849-walletconnect-safe-app)